# Service dependencies aren't been displaying on Service's dependencies's tab

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

My problem is that i need to add dependencies to my windows service, cause it's crashing when the windows system starts

I added the dependencies on ServicesDependedOn property in ServiceInstaller at the ProjectInstaller class, one per line as showing below.

```
MSDTC
MSSQL$MSSQLEXPRESS2008
```

/\ These are the Dependencies that need to be started before my service starts

After install the service i go to Service's dependencies's tab and there is no dependencies there, maybe i'm forgeting or i don't know what else to do, i'd never worked on it.

do someone know how to figure this out...

Thanks.

---

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue.  My problem was that I was using the Service Display Name and not the Service Name.  In your example above MSDTC would be correct and should work I'm not sure about the MSSQL item.